# How to estimate probability of a binomial passing a threshold?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, estimation, binomial-distribution

Let $X$ be a binomial random variable $X \sim Bi(p, t)$. ($t$ is the number of tosses)

Is there a way to estimate $$P(X \ge \alpha t + \beta)$$?

I know that I can write the probability exactly but it's not very useful as it's a sum which I'm not sure how to operate.

$t$ here is supposed to be finite, but even taking $t \to \infty$ doesn't really help because after normalizing the LHS goes to a normal but the RHS blows up

Have you any resource / advice?

Comment: Have you tried Markov or Chebyshev bounds?

Comment: Try a [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound).

Comment: @JonWarneke Thank you, but I would really appreciate the other direction.. That is $P(X \ge \alpha t + \beta) \ge something$

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks! But do you know of any bounds in the other direction?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Uhm actually with Chernoff I get $\displaystyle P(X \ge a) \ge 1 - \frac{E[e^{-tx}]}{e^{-ta}}$.. I'll see if it works. If you have any other suggestion in the meanwhile feel free! :D and thanks ;)